# How to group in fixed count ranges?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have one table with two columns (student_id,grade).

student_id is an integer and grade is a decimal number.

In case I have 1000 students and want to group them ordered by grade in groups of 10 students each.

Just to be clear, this should produce 100 groups. The first group cointains the 10 highest grades and the last group contains the 10 lowest grades.

How should I do that ? 
Optimization is always welcome.

Thank you very much.

Joao

Comment: No need for [SQL] in the title, given the sql tag.

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. There might not even be 10 different grades. Do you perhaps really mean "The first group cointains the 10 highest STUDENTS and the last group contains the 10 lowest STUDENTS." ?? If you do, then realize that it might not be possible, as groups of students with the same grade may span (cross) a group boundary based on number of students.

Comment: Charles, the first group contains the ids of the students that had the 10 highest grades and the respective grades. If there are 13 grades that equal maximum, the result I want is to have 10 of them in the first group and 3 of them in the second group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ntile` will give a ranking by an amount of buckets.

```
select student_id, ntile(100) over (order by grade desc) from student
```