# Query Optimization

Tags: sql, optimization, postgresql, query-optimization

That's my current query, it works but it is slow:

```
    SELECT row, MIN(flg) ||' to ' ||Max (flg) as xyz , avg(amt_won), count(*)
FROM(
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY flg))*100/
(SELECT  count(*)+100 as temprow FROM temporary_six_max) as row, flg, amt_won
FROM temporary_six_max 
    JOIN (
    SELECT id_player AS pid,  avg(flg_vpip::int)  AS flg 
    FROM temporary_six_max
    GROUP BY id_player 
    ) AS auxtable
    ON pid = id_player
) as auxtable2
group by 1
order by 1;
```

I am grouping in fixed (or almost fixed) count 100 ranges that are ordered by avg(flg_vpip) grouped by id_player.

Here I've pasted the results in case it may help to understand:
https://spreadsheets0.google.com/ccc?key=tFVsxkWVn4fMWYBxxGYokwQ&authkey=CNDvuOcG&authkey=CNDvuOcG#gid=0

I wonder if there is a better function to use than ROW_NUMBER() in this case and I feel like I am doing too many subselects but I don't know how to optimize it.

I'll appreciate very much any help.

If something is not clear just let me know.

Thank you.

EDIT:

The reason I created auxtable 2, is because when I use (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY flg), and use other agregate commands such as avg(amt_won) and count(*), which are essential, I get an error saying that flg should be in the aggregate function, but I can't order by an aggregate function of flg.

Comment: Please post the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE as well. And please explain what you are actually trying to achieve with the nested selects (I mean *auxtable4* not the derived table *auxtable2* Currently I don't understand the goal of that

Comment: I posted the EXPLAIN ANALYZE in the gdocs on the link above. The answer for the creation of auxtable4 and auxtable 2 are on the edited post. Thanks.

Comment: `max(row_number())` is essentially `count(*) over (...)`. But I still don't understand the calculations you do to that (dividing and the +100). But I do understand the intention now.

Comment: I multiply by 100 and then divide by the number of rows because after this I can make groups that are almost equally populated(in this case 100 groups). Count (*) works better, thank you very much : ) The + 100 is just a trick to group correctly.

Comment: I created a post ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453321/sql-how-to-group-in-fixed-count-ranges ), which basically asked how to create equally populated groups, but I don't think it is a very popular way, so I designed my own method, which is not fast. That is what the calculations do.

Comment: Google spreadsheets destroyed the indentation of the EXPLAIN ANALYZE.  Could you please add it to your question, formatted as code, so that the indentation is maintained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generated some data to test with like this:

```
create table temporary_six_max as
select id_player, flg_vpip,
       random()*100 * (case flg_vpip when 0 then 1 else -1 end) as amt_won
from (select (random()*1000)::int as id_player, random()::int as flg_vpip
      from generate_series(1,1000000)) source;
create index on temporary_six_max(id_player);
```

Your query runs successfully against that, but doesn't quite generate the same plan, I get a nested loop in the lower arm rather than a merge and a seq scan in the init-plan-- you haven't turned off enable_seqscan I hope?

A solution just using a single scan of the table:

```
select row, min(flg) || ' to ' || max(flg) as xyz, avg(amt_won), count(*)
from (select flg, amt_won, ntile(100) over(order by flg) as row
      from (select id_player as pid, amt_won,
                   avg(flg_vpip::int) over (partition by id_player) as flg
            from temporary_six_max
           ) player_stats
     ) chunks
group by 1
order by 1
```

The bad news is that this actually performs *worse* on my machine, especially if I bump work_mem up enough to avoid the first disk sort (making player_stats, sorting by flg). Although increasing work_mem did halve the query time, so I guess that is at least a start?

Having said that, my queries are running for about 5 seconds to process 10E6 input rows in temporary_six_max, which is an order of magnitude faster than you posted. Does your table fit into your buffer cache? If not, a single-scan solution may be much better for you. (Which version of Postgresql are you using? "explain (analyze on, buffers on) select..." will show you buffer hit/miss rates in 9.0, or just look at your "shared_buffers" setting and compare with the table size)